# Intersection of distinct, primed-ordered subgroups is trivial.

Tags: group-theory

$H$ and $K$ are different subgroups of a group $G$ such that $o(H) = o(K) = p$ where $p$ is prime. Show that $H \cap K = \{e\}$. Deduce that if $G$ has exactly $m$ distinct subgroup of prime order $p$ then total number of elements of order $p$ is $m(p-1)$.

Comment: Please use a title for your question which reflects its content (there is never a need to say «please help» in titles, as the whole purpose of this site is precisely that)

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Please read [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 3):

The intersection $H\cap K$ is a subgroup of $H$.

Can you make a list of all the subgroups of $H$?

Comment: Good hint. +1...

Comment: can anyone help me to prove it?/

Comment: Can you first answer my question? How many subgroups does $H$ have?